# MacOS Big Sur 11.6.1 Alfred 4.6 Can't catch the selected file's path

Tags: macos, workflow, alfred

In the past, in Alfred we could bind a hotkey to a selected file, and it would return to the path of the file:
[image]
[image]

After upgrading to Mac Big Sur, it now returns empty string:

[image]

Why does this happen, and how to recover the original behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

But I have found a new method to fix this problem. The code is as follows:

```
    #! /bin/bash

CurrentSelectPath=$(osascript <<EOF
tell application "Finder"
    set theItems to selection
    set filePath to (POSIX path of (the selection as alias))
  end tell
  set q to filePath
  return q
EOF
)
echo $CurrentSelectPath
```

Comment: Later, I searched Alfred's official forum and found that it was a permission problem. Just check Alfred in Preferences > Security and privacy > accessibility ☑️ It may be that MacOS Big Sur pays more attention to privacy